# How to implement touch scroll in Godot

Tags: scroll, scrollbar, godot, gdscript

I'm making a user interface for mobile devices and I need a way to scroll through my items vertically, I managed to do it using a Scroll Container. But the problem is that it takes up space and it won't work using swipe gestures, so my plan is to make the scroll bar the same size of the screen and make it invisible. So how and where do I tweak these settings? Or is there is a way to implement swipe gesture to scroll.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is easy to have the scrollcontainer scroll by a swipe gesture.
You have to make sure that all sub nodes of scroll container have a `mouse_filter` set to `pass` or `ignore`.

Check out [this github answer](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/21137#issuecomment-414959543).